# Deleting a child from Realtime database using Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I create a Realtime database and push data on it.
I need to delete a specific child but I couldn't because I don't know the random key which firebase generate for children how could I access specific child in order to delete it in Flutter.
[image: this image represent the Realtime database structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the child key you need to take a DataSnapshot then you can order the key

> `snapshot.key.toString()`

It will return all keys of the Realtime Database in the current level.

If you need to get an specific key you should link it with index of the user choice.

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              query: FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('journeys'),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                  Animation animation, int index) {
                try {
                  return Text(snapshot.key.toString());
                } catch (e) {
                  customSnackBar(context, e.toString(), 3, Colors.white24, Colors.brown, 17);
                }
              }),
```